# 2d random walk: expected time to hit enclosing square

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, random-walk

**Problem**: consider a random walk on a 2d square lattice. We start at the origin and each second we move by one unit either up, down, left or right with equal probability (equal to $1/4$). Suppose there is a square surrounding the origin of the plane, centered at $(0,0)$ and whose sides have length $L=4$, i.e. the vertices of the square are located at the four points $(\pm 2,\pm 2)$.

**Question**: what is the expected time required to hit the square?

Now, we can get an approximation of the expected time by computing the RMS distance, which is given by $$\sqrt{E(D_N^2)} = \sqrt{N}$$ where $D_N$ is the distance from the origin after $N$ seconds. However, this is obviously not the same as the expected distance itself, which would be $E(|D_N|)$. I know that the latter can be at least computed asymptotically (i.e. when $N\rightarrow \infty$), but for the problem in question we expect $N\sim 4$, which is clearly much smaller than infinity, so I would like to find a more accurate value (if possible!).

I have tried using the results from 1.4.2 in [this reference](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Elawler/reu.pdf), but I am stuck trying to compute $p_n(x,y;A)$, i.e. the probability of being at point $y$ at time $n$ when starting from point $x$, where $x,y \in A$. For example, let's say we want to compute $p_n(0,0)$, that is the probability of returning to the origin after $n$ steps *when there is no boundary*. It is known that this is equal to $$\begin{cases}p_{2n}(0,0) = 4^{-2n} {2n \choose n}^2\\ p_{2n+1}(0,0)=0 \end{cases}.$$
My issue is that I don't know how to compute this probability when *there is* a boundary. Clearly we must have $p_n(0,0;A)\le p_n(0,0)$ since some paths are not allowed anymore, but I'm not sure how to compute it exactly. Honestly I'm not even sure this is the right route to solve the problem.

I hope I stated the problem clearly. I have been away from statistics for a few years, so I'm quite rusty. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you split the events into $4$ groups, say $A_n$ being at $(0,0)$ after $n$ steps without having hit the square, $B_n$ being at $(\pm1,0)$ or $(0,\pm1)$ after $n$ steps without hit the square, $C_n$ being at $(\pm1,\pm1)$ after $n$ steps without having hit the square, and $D_n$ first hitting the square at the $n$th step, then you get $P(A_{n+1})=\frac14 P(B_n)$ and  $P(B_{n+1})=P(A_n)+\frac12 P(C_n)$ and $P(C_{n+1})=\frac12 P(B_n)$ and $P(D_n)=\frac14 P(B_n)+\frac12 P(C_n)$.  This will enable you to find $P(D_n)$ and so $\sum n\,P(D_n)$ as the expected time to hit the square

Comment: Alternatively, after one step you are at $(\pm1,0)$ or $(0,\pm1)$.  Then you either (a) hit the square on the next step or (b) hit the square after two steps or (c) are again at $(\pm1,0)$ or $(0,\pm1)$ after two steps.  This gives a very easily solved expression for the expected number of steps to hit the square

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to solve the problem by using the first method you proposed. I find that the expected time to hit the square should be 4.5, which is also what I find by running simulations.

However, I'm not sure I understand your second procedure, could you maybe elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: $4.5$ is correct.  With the second method, if $Z$ is the number of steps needed to hit the square from any of the $(\pm1,0)$ or $(0,\pm1)$ points then you get $\mathbb E[Z] = \frac14 \times 1 +\frac 14 \times 2 + \frac12 \times (2+\mathbb E[Z])$ implying $\mathbb E[Z] =\frac72$; then add $1$ for the initial step from $(0,0)$

Comment: @Henry I really like your solution, in this case, but can you still apply a similar reasoning when the boundary is not symmetrical?. For instance, how would you compute the expected time required to hit the line passing through (1,0) and (0,1)?

Comment: @SamanthaSmith It gets harder if not bounded on all sides.  In fact if that boundary line is extended so it also passes through $(5,-4)$ and $(-10,11)$ etc, then the expected number of steps is infinite (equivalent to a 1D random walk and a boundary at $+1$)

Comment: @Henry It is interesting because I have run some tests on python and the expected number of steps is always below 300. But I don't know why. I am a noobie in the theory of random walks so I don't know if any research work has been made in this direction.

Comment: @SamanthaSmith it is very unlikely to take 300 or more steps, but it is likely enough to drive the expectation to infinity

Comment: Really cool I guess... Probability always surprises me. What happens if we have a closed boundary? Is there any algorithmic procedure to compute the expected value?@Henry

Comment: There are a lot of available techniques: for example this is a [Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) and in this particular case there are several symmetries to help simplify the question.

Answer (score 5):

*From comments:*

If you split the events into $4$ groups, say $A_n$ being at $(0,0)$ after $n$ steps without having hit the square, $B_n$ being at $(±1,0)$ or $(0,±1)$ after $n$ steps without hit the square, $C_n$ being at $(±1,±1)$ after $n$ steps without having hit the square, and $D_n$ first hitting the square at the $n$th step, then you get

- $P(A_{n+1})=\frac14P(B_n)$
- $P(B_{n+1})=P(A_n)+\frac12P(C_n)$
- $P(C_{n+1})=\frac12P(B_n)$
- $P(D_{n+1})=\frac14P(B_n)+\frac12P(C_n)$.

This will enable you to find $P(D_n)$ and so $∑nP(D_n)$ as the expected time to hit the square.  You applied this and found the answer to be $4.5$, which is correct.

Alternatively, after one step you are at $(±1,0)$ or $(0,±1)$. Then you either

1. hit the square on the next step or
2. hit the square after two steps or
3. are again at $(±1,0)$ or $(0,±1)$ after two steps.

This gives a easily solved expression for the expected number of steps to hit the square.  If $Z$ is the number of steps needed to hit the square from any of the $(±1,0)$ or $(0,±1)$ points then you get $E[Z]=\frac14×1+\frac14×2+\frac12×(2+E[Z])$ implying $E[Z]=\frac72$; then add $1$ for the initial step from $(0,0)$ to get $\frac92=4.5$ again.